# Continuous trigger not found in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Runtime: Spark 2.3.0, Scala 2.11 (Databricks 4.1 ML beta)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import scala.concurrent.duration._

//kafka settings and df definition goes here

val query = df.writeStream.format("parquet")
.option("path", ...)
.option("checkpointLocation",...)
.trigger(continuous(30000))
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
.start
```

Throws error not found: value continuous

Other attempts that did not work:

```scala
.trigger(continuous = "30 seconds") //as per Databricks blog
// throws same error as above

.trigger(Trigger.Continuous("1 second")) //as per Spark docs
// throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown type of trigger: ContinuousTrigger(1000)
```

References:

(Databricks Blog) 
https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/20/low-latency-continuous-processing-mode-in-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-3-0.html

(Spark guide) 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#continuous-processing

(Scaladoc) https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark 2.3.0 does not support parquet under continuous streams, you would have to use streams based on [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/), console or memory.

To quote the [continuous processing mode in structured streaming](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/20/low-latency-continuous-processing-mode-in-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-3-0.html) blog post:

> You can set the optional Continuous Trigger in queries that satisfy the following conditions: Read from supported sources like Kafka and write to supported sinks like Kafka, memory, console.

Answer (score 0):

As the following spark code, only the sinks who implements the `StreamWriteSupport` interface can use `ContinuousTrigger`.

```scala
    (sink, trigger) match {
      case (v2Sink: StreamWriteSupport, trigger: ContinuousTrigger) =>
        UnsupportedOperationChecker.checkForContinuous(analyzedPlan, outputMode)
        new StreamingQueryWrapper(new ContinuousExecution(
          sparkSession,
          userSpecifiedName.orNull,
          checkpointLocation,
          analyzedPlan,
          v2Sink,
          trigger,
          triggerClock,
          outputMode,
          extraOptions,
          deleteCheckpointOnStop))
      case _ =>
        new StreamingQueryWrapper(new MicroBatchExecution(
          sparkSession,
          userSpecifiedName.orNull,
          checkpointLocation,
          analyzedPlan,
          sink,
          trigger,
          triggerClock,
          outputMode,
          extraOptions,
          deleteCheckpointOnStop))
```

And only three sinks have implemented this interface, `ConsoleSinkProvider`,
`KafkaSourceProvider`,
`MemorySinkV2`.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 3.0.1 the continuous processing mode is experimental and supported for special query types dependent on their *Source* and *Sink*.

According to the documentation on [Continuous Processing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#continuous-processing) the following queries are supported and it seems that writing parquet is not supported:

> As of Spark 2.4, only the following type of queries are supported in the continuous processing mode.
>
> ```
> Operations: Only map-like Dataset/DataFrame operations are supported in continuous mode, that is, only projections (select, map, flatMap, mapPartitions, etc.) and selections (where, filter, etc.).
>    All SQL functions are supported except aggregation functions (since aggregations are not yet supported), current_timestamp() and current_date() (deterministic computations using time is challenging).
> Sources:
>    Kafka source: All options are supported.
>    Rate source: Good for testing. Only options that are supported in the continuous mode are numPartitions and rowsPerSecond.
> Sinks:
>    Kafka sink: All options are supported.
>    Memory sink: Good for debugging.
>    Console sink: Good for debugging. All options are supported. Note that the console will print every checkpoint interval that you have specified in the continuous trigger.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 second"))`

This will work, as I had the same issue and it got resolved using this method.