# No output after aggregating from parquet to parquet with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I have got an input dataset with schema:

| ID | Name | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | "Book name 1" | "liked it" |
| 57 | "Book name 2" | "really liked it" |

This dataset is placed on `HDFS` in `parquet`. I need to calculate rows counts for each book and write result to other parquet.

When I do this aggregation with console output, everything seems to be OK:

```py
rows_count_query =\
    spark\
        .readStream\
        .schema(user_rating_schema)\
        .parquet(path=src_data_path)\
        .groupBy("Name")\
        .agg(fun.count(fun.col("Name")).alias("RowCount"))\
        .writeStream\
        .format("console")\
        .outputMode("complete")\
        .start()
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------+
|                Name|RowCount|
+--------------------+--------+
|Annabel (Delirium...|       1|
|   Plays and Masques|       1|
|       Sein und Zeit|       1|
|A Blind Man Can S...|       6|
|Notes From a Defe...|       1|
|   سگ کشی، فیلم‌نامه|      25|
|            Goldfish|       2|
|The Gilded Chain ...|       1|
|Duct Tape and a T...|       1|
|The Ugliest House...|       1|
|On Stalin's Team:...|       1|
|Normative Theory ...|       1|
|پاداش آخر سال - م...|       3|
|14 Minutes: A Run...|       1|
|Emergency: This B...|       2|
|    Whitney, My Love|       3|
|Archangel's Proph...|       1|
|The Dialogues of ...|       2|
|Black Cat (Gemini...|       2|
|              Easter|       1|
+--------------------+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I want to have this result written in `parquet`.

To do it, I do the following:

```
rows_count_query =\
    spark\
        .readStream\
        .schema(user_rating_schema)\
        .parquet(path=input_path)\
        .select("Name", fun.current_timestamp().alias("CurrentTime"))\
        .withWatermark("CurrentTime", delayThreshold="1 minute")\
        .groupBy("Name", "CurrentTime")\
        .agg(fun.count(fun.col("Name")).alias("RowCount"))\
        .writeStream\
        .format("parquet")\
        .option("path", output_path)\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")\
        .outputMode("append")\
        .start()
```

Reading output path as `Spark SQL` dataset shows that it is empty:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(putput_path)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+--------+
|Name|CurrentTime|RowCount|
+----+-----------+--------+
+----+-----------+--------+
```

I added timestemp with current time as it is required for `watermark`, which is requierd for `append` output mode when doing aggregations. Why there is nothing written in output file? What to do to have result written in `parquet`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to adjust the trigger interval (continuous="1 second") based on your requirements.

```py
rows_count_query =\
    spark\
        .readStream\
        .schema(user_rating_schema)\
        .parquet(path=input_path)\
        .select("Name", fun.current_timestamp().alias("CurrentTime"))\
        .withWatermark("CurrentTime", delayThreshold="1 minute")\
        .groupBy("Name", "CurrentTime")\
        .agg(fun.count(fun.col("Name")).alias("RowCount"))\
        .writeStream\
        .format("parquet")\
        .option("path", output_path)\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")\
        .outputMode("append")\
        .trigger(continuous="1 second")\ # add this line
        .start()
```

By making [these modifications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#continuous-processing), your streaming query should continuously process the incoming data, calculate the row counts, and write the results to the specified parquet output path.

Comment: According to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952042/continuous-trigger-not-found-in-structured-streaming), triggers are not supported for `parquet` data source. When I tried adding `.trigger(continuous="1 second")\ # add this line` I ve recieved an error message: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o246.start.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown type of trigger: ContinuousTrigger(1000)...`.